# Not able to change background color if a <li> has a specific id

Tags: css, html-lists, stylesheet

I have a unordered list where every `<li>` has a different ID and a white background. Now when the id = me (`<li id="me">`) it should change the background color to red instead of white.

Please see my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mauricederegt/s2dHJ/

I've tried:

```
#overview li, #me {
blabla
}
#me {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

and

```
#overview li, #me li {
blabla
}
#me li{
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

etc, but none worked

Hope there is a solution for this.

Kind regards,

Comment: Yea it is.  My bad, should be #FF000, changed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write like this :

```
#overview #me {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

Because the power `#overview li` more then `#me`. So for overrite we have to define like this `#overview #me`.

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/s2dHJ/2/

Comment: Thanks, this works great. Also good explanation of why it didn't worked. Very helpful!

Comment: You may find this helpful http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#me {
    background-color: #FF0000 !important;
}
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/s2dHJ/1/)

Even though I wouldn't recommend the use of the `!important`, you seem to have other styles overriding your desired style. Either fix all the styles so they inherit the way you want them to, or force it as shown.

Answer (score 0):

Give div container a class instead of an id. ID's are much more restrictive than classes in CSS. So, ID overwrites the property of its inherited class.

```
<div class="overview">
    <ul>
        <li id="1234">
             This one should have a WHITE bg    
        </li>
        <li id="me">
             This one should have a RED bg    
        </li>
        <li id="567">
            This one should have a WHITE bg    
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>​


.overview {
   padding-top: 30px;
   background-color: #2daebf;
   height: 468px;
   width: 182px;
}
.overview li {
   list-style: none;
   float: left;
   width: 160px;
   padding: 3px;
   background-color: #FFF;
   border-radius: 3px;
   margin: 0 7px 3px 7px;
}
```